# How to accept null values in Aurelia validation with properties dependent on each other?

Tags: validation, aurelia

I'm trying to validate some temperature values which are dependent on each other but I want to accept null values for them as well. For example I have the following code:

```
VadliationRules.customRule(
"minT",
(value, obj: Object, min) => {
 let converted = parseFloat(value)
 return converted >= min && converted < obj.MaxTemperature
},
'');

ValidationRules.customRule(
"maxT",
(value, obj: Object, max) => {
 let converted = parseFloat(value)
 return converted <= max && converted > obj.MinTemperature
},
'');

ValidationRules
.ensure((p: Object) => p.MinTemperature)
.satisfiesRule('minT', -15.0)
.withMessageKey('min_temp')

.ensure((p: Object) => p.MaxTemperature)
.satisfiesRule('maxT', 50.0)
.withMessageKey('max_temp')

.on(Object)

let MinTemperature : number;
let MaxTemperature : number;
```

I have tried the following options but they doesn't seem to work(because of the dependency on the other propery I suppose)

```
// Example 1
VadliationRules.customRule(
"minT",
(value, obj: Object, min) => {
 let converted = parseFloat(value)
 return converted >= min && converted < obj.MaxTemperature || converted == undefined || obj.MaxTemperature == null
},
'');

// Example 2
VadliationRules.customRule(
"minT",
(value, obj: Object, min) => {
 let converted = parseFloat(value)
 return converted >= min && converted < obj.MaxTemperature || converted == undefined || converted.toString() == ""
},
'');
```

How can I accept null values for both field at the same time satisfying the dependecy on the other properties?

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
return converted >= min && (converted < obj.MaxTemperature || obj.MaxTemperature == null)
```

1. When not using parentheses, when your obj.MaxTemperature == null, it will pass regardless of your first check
2. FYI, obj.MaxTemperature == null also checks for undefined, so you can omit that part (see http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3)